# Как можно расставить знаки препинания в бессоюзном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Наверное, по-разному можно расставить знаки. А какой вариант выберете вы и как его объясните?

***Правильно говорят () любви много в человеке () бесконечный объем.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну что ж, попробуем:

*Правильно говорят: любви много в человеке — бесконечный объем.*

Что именно говорят? Это пояснение. Поэтому двоеточие. Тире сложнее объяснить, но интуитивно почему-то хочется именно его поставить.

Comment: Спасибо, Артем. Тире действительно на месте. Но для полноты ответа желательно объяснить постановку тире. Кроме того, есть еще один вариант, а какой?

Comment: Понятия не имею... Запятая вместо двоеточия?

Comment: Да, верно, в тексте стояла запятая. Правильно говорят, любви мнОго в человеке — бесконечный объем. Двоеточие здесь пояснительное, но оно обозначает частный вид — изъяснительные отношения. В этом случае первую часть можно считать вводным предложением, заменяющим слова автора. Поэтому запятая как вариант ставится по правилам. Но интересно, почему автор отказался от классического двоеточия. Вводная конструкция в состав предложения не входит и не требует особой интонации с увеличенной паузой — мы только едва намечаем ее. Предложение фактически состоит из двух, а не из трех частей.

Comment: При этом главной является центральная часть — логическим ударением выделено слов "много". А третья часть присоединительная со значением уточнения (как много). Поэтому ставится тире. Вот такое интересное предложение, а вам спасибо и за участие, и за ответы.

Comment: А вам за вопрос спасибо и за то, что всё по полочкам разложили и очков мне дали! :)